# First panel open on init with custom accordion-angular

Tags: angular

I created a library with a custom accordion in angular with bind event for auto close when other panel is clicked in "Toggle", my problem is that I need the first panel open at start by default.

here is a stackblitz with the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbztkc?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I tried to bind other event but I can´t  figure how bind that event to my previous one without breaking things, try a custom directive, and some commands on init, nothing works

I want this at start:
[image: How should start]

thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a initial value to `activeTitle`

```
 activeTitle: string = 'Documento 1';
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u3vjhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)